# Python - instance attribute defined outside __init__()

Tags: python, architecture, initialization, definition

I get the warning in question for the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Autocomplete(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list = []

    def build(self, width, height, entries):
        # I get the warning for the following 8 lines:
        self._entries = entries
        self.listbox_height = height
        self.entry_width = width
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.text, width=self.entry_width)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width)
        self.dropdown = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width, background="#cfeff9",
                                takefocus=0)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()
        return self
root = Frame(Tk())
autocomplete = Autocomplete(root).build(74, 10, entries)
root.pack()
autocomplete.pack()
mainloop()
```

How should I fix this? I tried to move everything to init but then I had some errors for passing the arguments in the line I was creating the Autocompelete object. So please provide me with all the changes I have to make. not just smth like you have to move them.
I could fix the warning by adding 8 definition lines assigning None to all the variables but I think that's such a stupid solution. So what is the right thing to do?

Comment: *"I could fix the warning by adding 8 definition lines assigning None to all the variables"*... that is what the warning is telling you to do. In general having attributes suddenly appear on an object that weren't defined in the `__init__` method can make debugging more difficult.

Comment: also, this is pretty highly dependent on the linter you're using.

Comment: @turbulencetoo I use pycharm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's always important to keep in mind that not all Warnings require fixing. Warnings are just Warnings. They are supposed to point out a specific part of the code because it's a "common" source of problems. But sometimes you need/want to do it that way.

> I could fix the warning by adding 8 definition lines assigning None to all the variables

That's just "silencing" the Warnings, in my opinion that's just as good as ignoring the Warnings.

> So what is the right thing to do?

The right way would be to just use `__init__`. I did a quick test and I don't have any problems.

However that's just an example how one could do it. I haven't checked what `Frame` wants as arguments for `__init__` so it could lead to conflicts:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Autocomplete(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        width, height, entries = kwargs.pop('width'), kwargs.pop('height'), kwargs.pop('entries')
        super(Autocomplete, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.list = []
        self._entries = entries
        self.listbox_height = height
        self.entry_width = width
        self.text = StringVar()
        self.entry = ttk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.text, width=self.entry_width)
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width)
        self.dropdown = Listbox(self.frame, height=self.listbox_height, width=self.entry_width, background="#cfeff9",
                                takefocus=0)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.frame.pack()
        self.listbox.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N)
        self.dropdown.grid_forget()

root = Frame(Tk())
autocomplete = Autocomplete(root, width=74, height=10, entries=entries)
root.pack()
autocomplete.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks my problem was with not adding width, height, entries = kwargs.pop('width'), kwargs.pop('height'), kwargs.pop('entries')! I didn't know what kwargs are and I was getting errors bc of that. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would also add that as of python 3.3, this also hints about missing an optimization feature for each instance’s `__dict__` when any attribute is set outside of the `__init__` method.

As stated in [Fluent Python 2nd Edition](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/fluent-python-2nd/9781492056348/), Chapter 3, page 103:

> Python’s default behavior is to store instance attributes in a special `__dict__` attribute, which is a dict attached to each instance. Since PEP 412—Key-Sharing Dictionary was implemented in Python 3.3, instances of a class can share a common hash table, stored with the class. That common hash table is shared by the `__dict__` of each new instance that has the same attributes names as the first instance of that class when `__init__` returns. Each instance `__dict__` can then hold only its own attribute values as a simple array of pointers. Adding an instance attribute after `__init__` forces Python to create a new hash table just for the `__dict__` of that one instance (which was the default behavior for all instances before Python 3.3). According to PEP 412, this opti‐ mization reduces memory use by 10% to 20% for object-oriented programs.

There’s further explanation of the internal optimizations at [FluentPython: Internals of sets and dicts](https://www.fluentpython.com/extra/internals-of-sets-and-dicts/#key_sharing_dict_sec)